# "Хаотичное" расположение изображений в галерее

Tags: javascript, css, изображения

Ребят, нужна помощь! Клиентка хочет сделать расположение статей в виде фото, как она сказала, "хаотичном расположении". Скинула нарисованный ею пример.
Игрался с размерами, отступами, скриптом Packery - всё не то.
Есть идеи, как такое сделать?

Работа сейчас висит по [этой ссылке](http://top.xslt.pw/ru)

[image: Скрин]

Answer (score 2):

Это невозможно, т.к. это никакое не хаотичное расположение. Просите ТЗ.